# VBA OLE Error when tring to new created xlsx file Attachment in Lotus Notes

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I am tring to send some new Excle files that i created before.
When i try to send them with Lotus Notes i get an OLE error but when i try to send a test file it works without Problem. Can someone give me a tip where the Problem lies?

This i my Attachment part in the E-Mail function:

```
stAttachment = EmailAttachment
Set AttachMe = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("stAttachment")
Set EmbedObj = AttachMe.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", stAttachment, "stAttachment")
```

Here i put the targent file:

```
    Filename = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Excel Notes\test.xlsm"
    Filename = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Excel Notes\generated.xlsm"

    EMail.EMailBuild EmailAdress, EmailHeader, EmailText, Filename
```

when i try the test file it functions but when i set the generatet file i get this error

waiting for another application to complete an OEL action

Comment: I guess the file which has been generated is still in use? Did you close the file properly ?

Comment: Your question indicates 'xlsx' but your code indicates 'xlsm'. Is one of those a typo??  Secondly: Is the VBA script actually running in the file that you are trying to attach?

Comment: I tried it with xlsx and xlsm there is the same error. The file was generated in an other Excle file from an other excle file and then                   `saved.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWindow.Close`

Comment: How does the EMailBuild embed the attachment ? as File or as OLE ?

Comment: you see this Part in my orginal Post what i also dont understand is that even after restarting and only tring to send the file that i had created beforhand i get the error but the normal file still works fine. So i think i make an error when i create the file or how i attach it.

Comment: where stAttachment is the filepath :
Set EmbedObj = AttachMe.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", stAttachment)